# IIS 10 - ULR Rewrite rule for stopping Image Hotlinking - when working also affects the domain host itself

Tags: iis, hotlinking

**Windows 2016 Server** running **IIS 10** with the **URL Rewrite** Module installed.
The servers are set up in a server Farm.

I've been messing around with this for the last 48 hours and cannot, for the life of me, figure out why it is not working as it is supposed to work.
I've looked at a video showing how to set it up and how it works, and I've mimicked what was done in the video, and nothing, still cannot get it to work.

This is what happens.
Using this code below will work; as you notice, it has the pattern="Pattern: "
However, the leading site that hosts the images has its images replaced with the stop-hotlinking.png image as well.
So, in theory, it works, but the hosting site has no access to its images to display.
If I remove (pattern="Pattern: "), it does not work.

To sum it up.
The below code will display the "stop-hotlinking.png" image on all outside sites, as well as the hosting site.

```
 <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="STOP-Hot-Linking" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*\.(gif|jpg|png)$" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="Pattern: ^$" negate="true"/>
              <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="Pattern: ^https?://(www\.)?domain\.com/.*$" negate="true"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/graph/stop-hotlinking.png" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I even tried it with the pattern as this, and it will display the stop-hotlinking.png on all sites including the hosting site.

```
<add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="^http://(.*\.)?domain\.com/.*$" negate="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was assisted on another forum, and this was the issue.
I was testing the same image on multiple domains we own.
And that was the biggest problem, was the image would get cached, even when Google Tools was open, it would still cache it for whatever reason, we never could figure it out.
I changed to another image from the hosting site, and it started working.
We also found out that Google Chrome needed a referral meta tag in the head of the hosting sites page.

```
<meta name="referrer" content="origin">
```

Once all the above was taken care of and the following code in place. It started working.

```
<rule name="Prevent Image Hotlinking" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$" />
<conditions>
   <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="^https?://(www\.)?(?:DomainOne\.com|DomainTwo\.com|DomainThree\.com)/.*$" negate="true"/>
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="/graph/stop-hotlinking.png" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

In the above, you will see there are multiple domains, this is to allow images to be hosted on their domains, and all other domains will get the STOP image.

This is completed.
I want to think Jalpa for trying to assist.
And gr8gonzo from the other forum for helping me out in this long venture.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample you could refer:

let's say I have 2 sites in my iis server and I would like to set a rule in the test site to not allow other domain sites to use images so I will set a URL rewrite rule in the test site.

test site index page contact:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test.com title page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>test.com</h2>
<img src="http://test.com/img.jpg">
</html>
```

[image]

now i am trying to access image from the test site to the test2 site:

[image]

below is the rule i have set in my test site:

```
<rule name="Prevent Image Hotlinking" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$" />
<conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="^$" negate="true" />
    <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="^http://test.com/.*$" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="/hotlink.jpg" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

Note: hard refresh your page in bwroser if it does not work or you could try to open page in private mode.

Comment: Same issue. I am using Google Chrome Developer Tools with "Disable cache (While DevTools is open)" To get live data updates. And as before, your code works. However, it is also affecting the hosting domain as well.

Comment: could you share how you are implementing it like with sample

Comment: Can you be more specific? Implementing which part? The web.config, is as I have it shown in my post, but with the Hosting Domain, in place of the domain.

Comment: i mean details of the site. or you could try to use the logRewrittenUrl="true"  in your rule and enable failed request tracing and share the log with us

Comment: I can do that. I am setting up the Failed Request Tracing now, and am on the page for "Define Trace Conditions" which should I select, and what should I add-in, in order to get a trace on this?

Comment: try this code "  <tracing>
<traceFailedRequests>
<add path="*">
<traceAreas>
                        <add provider="ASP" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="ASPNET" areas="Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="ISAPI Extension" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Rewrite" verbosity="Verbose" />
</traceAreas>
<failureDefinitions timeTaken="00:00:00" statusCodes="100-900" />
</add>
</traceFailedRequests>
</tracing>"

Comment: I tried it, and it did not write anything to the logs. The website itself host images, and the images are shown on the page in a click-by-click gallery. People have been hotlinking to the images on the site for years, and it is time to shut them down.

Comment: you can find the log on this path C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles

Comment: I changed it to G:\inetpub, and there is nothing on either of the server's instances. All share the same IIS config, so once I enabled and created the Log rule on the main, it copied it over to the rest of them. All directories are empty.

Comment: make sure you have selected enabled checkbox in FREB [image](https://imgur.com/a/Nhq4z9C)

Comment: I created two simple pages, both hosted on their own domains with just an image link to the hosting image URL, and when I enabled the rule, they both turned out to be blocked, even the hosting site. So, it is clearly just not working. I did a quick search to see if maybe there was something that needed to be changed with the fact this is running in an IIS Server Farm, and I got nothing, which has me believe that there should not be any difference. Going to bed will deal with this again tomorrow. Thank you for the assistance so far, Jalpa.

Comment: add the hosting site domain in the condition to avoid blocking it self

Comment: where you have test.com, that is the hosting domain in my case. Is there another way to write it, if so, then I have been doing and misunderstanding this the whole time?

Comment: check this [image](https://imgur.com/a/kXdfUDR)